# How to better secure the toilet fill hose?

Tags: plumbing, toilet, valve

I was having issues with my old fill valve (a Fluidmaster) no longer filling and just dripping in to the tank, and also not shutting off reliably. So I decided to replace it.

I got the new fill valve installed and no leaks. But, the rubber hose doesn't have a way to attach snugly to whatever flush valve/overflow pipe that is currently installed. The hose fits down in to the opening/connector at the top, and doesn't fit around the protrusion, so it's a bit loose. I decided to use some electrical tape to help secure it, as I didn't have a way to attach it using the clip on the single long overflow pipe you get with Fluidmaster overflow pipe.

Is this OK? I've flushed it several times and everything seems to flush/fill properly. I'm just a bit concerned about the fill hose not fitting by design, and potentially coming loose.

Any suggestions on how to improve the fit here?

original valve installation:
[image: original valve installation]

new valve installed:
[image: new valve installed]

Fill tube secured with electrical tape:
[image: Fill tube secured with electrical tape]

Comment: So long as it works and the tube stays in place, you're fine. However, I don't think it's likely that the electrical tape will hold for long - it's really not designed for wet environments. Are you sure the blue thing on the fill hose of the new valve isn't supposed to be the clip holding the hose in place?

Comment: The hose is thinner than port it connects to. I think the clip is supposed to go around the hose on the fill valve (I've updated that since taking the photo. There's another blue clip just like that that came with spare, but it doesn't seem to be the right size / shape to fit around the protrusion and hold the hose in

Comment: Checking the obvious: What do the instructions say about it?

Comment: @FreeMan the instructions show using a clip and attaching it to a FluidMaster flush valve. I didn't want to install that since it involves taking the tank off and is a bit out of my comfort zone. The clip doesn't work with the canister flush valve that's already installed (Kohler).

Comment: Sounds like an answer, @JACK!

Comment: The hardest part of taking the tank off is drying it thoroughly enough to not drip and/or cleaning up the drips once you remove it. It's not like the bowl itself where there's a wax ring to deal with - it' a rubber or foam gasket that's reusable. Of course, since you've got it apart, may as well sport an extra couple of bucks to replace it, just to be on the safe side.

Answer (score 1):

Cut a small piece off of the old white hose and slip it over the end of the black hose and insert the end into the port.

Answer (score -1):

Could consider just using the old hose in its entirety. This should solve the issue with it not securely fitting where you currently have the red tape.

Where the other end of the pipe fits, it pushes over a fitting. I the pipe is too loose here, you can always clamp it down with a Jubilee clamp, or insert bit of the new pipe on the nib, and then insert the new pipe bit into the old pipe.